# how to load a dll into remote process in which kernel32.dll not yet loaded

Tags: api, loadlibrary, kernel32, remote-process

i want to load my dll into address space of remote process in which kernel32.dll is not yet loaded . so to load my dll into remote process i need LoadLibrary function but wchich is present in kernel32.dll . so please suggest me how to achieve the loading dll into another remote process in which Kernel32.dll is not loaded yet.

Comment: I'm curious: how have you got a process without kernel32.dll??

Comment: process is launching but it is not started completely so i have to load my dll before it starts completely i mean i  have to wait till kernel32.dll is loaded then i have to inject.